# Recent gyroscope support from Corona SDK seems to be non-responsive

Tags: iphone, coronasdk, gyroscope

I'm using a recent daily build of the **Corona SDK** (version 2001.562) to add gyroscope support to an existing application. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the `event-handling` function for the gyroscope to fire. The application is running on an **iPod touch, version 4.3.3**.

I attach the gyroscope to an event handler like so:

```
if system.hasEventSource("gyroscope") then
    feedbackFile = io.open(system.pathForFile("log.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory), "a");
    feedbackFile:write((os.clock()-startupTime).."\tgyroscope on\n");
    io.close(feedbackFile);
    Runtime:addEventListener( "gyroscope", onGyroscopeDataReceived )
else
    feedbackFile = io.open(system.pathForFile("log.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory), "a");
    feedbackFile:write((os.clock()-startupTime).."\tgyroscope off\n");
    io.close(feedbackFile);
end
```

When I launch the application on the device, then close it and download the resource files, I find that `log.txt` contains the line with a `timestamp` and "gyroscope on". Good so far!

On to the event-handling function:

```
local function onGyroscopeDataReceived(event)

    feedbackFile = io.open(system.pathForFile("log.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory), "a");
    feedbackFile:write((os.clock()-startupTime).."\tgyroscope reading delta="..event.deltaRotation..",x="..event.xRotation..",y="..event.yRotation..",z="..event.zRotation.."\n");
    io.close(feedbackFile);
end
```

This line of information never appears in the `log.txt` file!

Please advise. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspected the problem might lie with my device, but I've tried the above code on another iPod touch, version 4.3.3, and gotten the same disappointing results.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is event.deltaRotation doesn't exist. You might mean event.deltaTime.

Then when you concatenate a nil value, Lua throws an error and your write code never gets completed. (The latest daily build will now print out a message when you encounter a Lua error on a device.)

The documentation shows how to compute your own deltaDegrees or deltaRadians:
http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/events/gyroscope/eventxrotation

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess but it may be your listener is never called --- I noticed your onGyroscopeDataReceived function is local.  If that's the case, then you need to make sure the variable is declared prior to the addEventListener call.